# Can I put a standard light kit on this ceiling fan that had a built-in light?

Tags: ceiling-fan, light, socket

Does this ceiling fan accept a standard light kit, or is this something proprietary?

The bulb in this low-profile ceiling fan violently died. After replacing the bulb it does not work. I intend to replace the light kit, but I don't think this fan has a standard light kit connection.  The original E12 socket attached via a metal bracket and 2 screws and a piece of cardboard(?!?).  While there are 3 screws around the housing, they were used for holding the globe onto the light rather than for a separate light kit.  Can those 3 screw holes be used to attach a light kit?  The diameter of the bottom of the white housing is exactly 90mm.

Or is there some other way I should repair this?

Volmeter shows no power at the socket.  So I conclude that either the socket or the switch are bad.  I could cut & test the wires before the E12 socket.  If there is no power there then I conclude the switch died.  But I hesitate to do that until I get this answer first.

[image: Ceiling fan with built-in light kit and broken E12 socket]
[image: Light kit mount onto the fan base]

Comment: Clarify "violently died", please. Bulb failure should not be able to damage the fixture unless something else was extremely wrong. And if the fixture died, I'd want to know exactly how and make sure other damage hadn't been done at the same time.

Comment: The bulb intermittently flickered for a long period of time.  When it died it made an electrical arcing sound.  In retrospect, I think the switch inside the housing was the problem, not the bulb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ceiling fan does not support a light kit.  I hired an electrician to replace it with a [Harbor Breeze Armitage 42-in](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Harbor-Breeze-Armitage-42-in-White-LED-Indoor-Flush-Mount-Ceiling-Fan-with-Light-Kit-4-Blade/1000195087) which comes with a light, and also does not support a light kit.  It seems that the inexpensive flush-mount fan & light combinations do not have the proper mounting for a light kit.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the light will not work. If it is the switch, or the wiring to it, another light kit will still not give you a working light. Check the switch to see if you have power coming in and out, and if so verify that the power is getting to the socket at the termination point to the bulb. Do the same with the neutral. The results will tell you what needs to be replaced or repaired. Not knowing this and replacing the socket with a new light kit (if it is available) will have undesired results.